# Image Classification with TensorFlow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150


train_data_dir = 'flowers/train'
validation_data_dir = 'flowers/validation'
nb_train_samples = 2500
nb_validation_samples = 1000
epochs = 20
batch_size = 50


if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')


validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')


model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)


model.save_weights('first_flowers_try.h5')
```

We trained this model for classify 5 image classes. We used 500 images for each class for train the model and 200 images for each class to validate the model. We used keras in tensorflow backend.It uses data that can be downloaded at:
https://www.kaggle.com/alxmamaev/flowers-recognition

In our setup, we:

- created a data/ folder
- created train/ and validation/ subfolders inside data/
- created daisy/, dandelion/, rose/ ,sunflower/ and tulip/ subfolders inside train/ and validation/
- put the 500 images in each data/train/daisy, dandelion, rose, sunflower and tulip
- put the 200 images in each data/validation/daisy, dandelion, rose, sunflower and tulip
  So that we have 500 training examples for each class, and 200 validation examples for each class.

How can we predict/ test and identify another image using this trained model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `model.load_weights()` from the file you saved them to. Then you get a sample image you need a prediction for and call `model.predict( [sample_image] )` and use the result returned as a prediction.

Comment: But whe we try this, generates some errors in the code!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 52, in run_file
   pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
   exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/shasi/PycharmProjects/cats_dogs/classifier_from_little_data_script_1.py", line 119, in <module>
   model.load_weight('data/first_try.h5')

Comment: model.load_weight('data/first_try.h5')
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'load_weight'

Answer (score 2):

Construct your model as you did upon training

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Load model' weights from disk

```
model.load_weights('first_flowers_try.h5')
```

Load new image. Because we are only using one image we have to expand dims - add another dimension.

```
from keras.preprocessing import image

img_path = 'path_to_your_new_image'
#img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224)) # if a you want a spesific image size
img = image.load_img(img_path)
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = x*1./255 #rescale as training
```

Make Prediction

```
prediction = model.predict(x) #Vector with the prob of each class
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [keras' documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#the-sequential-model-api), you will have to use `predict(self, x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)`. Since you use the Softmax as an activation function in your final layer, this will return the probability of each class. If you just want the most probable class, you will have to take the one with the highest probability:

```
class_list = [class1, class2, class3, class4, class5] #A list of your classes
model.load_weights('first_flowers_try.h5') #Loads the saved weights
predicted_vector = model.predict(path_to_your_new_image) #Vector with the prob of each class
print(class_list[np.argmax(predicted_vector)) #Prints ellement with highest prob
```

Now, about getting class_list, you can try this:

```
import os
class_list = os.listdir('train')
class_list = sorted(class_list)
```

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: But we did not declared classes, so when we try this, it generates some error! If we need to declare classes, how can we declare as our code?

Comment: Edited the post above to give you an example with how to create the list. Check glob's documentation for the right parameters.

Comment: BTW, in @lenik solution (I comment here because I don't have enough reputation to comment there), probably you have misspelled `model.load_weights()` to `model.load_weight()`. This is why you get the error.

Comment: It does not work too. Can you please edit the code and send it? It will be verry helpful..

Comment: Edited. If you still get an error, give me some info about this.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'data/train'

Comment: You have to adjust the path based on your file structure.